# Flask+MySQL. App reloads the same page instead of routing and it fails to add values to mysql db

Tags: python, mysql, flask, web-development-server

*I know there is much of code below, but i had to show the html/css/js and flask+mysql codes* for better understanding. Ask if anything is not clear.

The problem is that, after i give the credentials in the register page and i submit, i expect for it to add the values to database and to route to the login page, but what it does actually, is that it reloads the same page, and the link look like this,

**i.e.:**

**"http://127.0.0.1:5000/register/patient?name_surname=jack+stathem&email=jsm%40outlook.com&ssn=123456789&age=40"**

i am having some semantic error and i cant figure out how to fix.

***Thank you***

```js
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  // ... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
    // document.getElementById("nextBtn").value = "submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  // ... and run a function that displays the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form... :
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    //...the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false:
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

```css
 /* Style the form */
#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

/* Style the input fields */
input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* Mark the active step: */
.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block head %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style/docnpatientreg.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap-tagsinput.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <form id="regForm">

        <h1>Register:</h1>

        <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
        <div class="tab">Name:
            <p><input name="name_surname" type="text" placeholder="First name..."></p>
            <p><input name='email' type="email" placeholder="E-mail..."></p>
            <p><input name='ssn' type="text" placeholder="SSN"></p>
            <p><input name='age' type="text" placeholder="Age"></p>
        </div>



        <div style="overflow:auto;">
            <div style="float:right;">
                <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
                <button type="submit" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
        <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
            <span class="step"></span>
        </div>

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='functionality/docnpatientreg.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap-tagsinput.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Flask+MySQL

**Note**: It is not the whole code, if needed i will post it

```
@medAI.route('/')  
def main_base():

  cursor.execute("select * from Patients")
  result = cursor.fetchall()
  print(result)

  return render_template('main.html')

@medAI.route('/register/<where>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register(where):

  if where == "patient":
      if request.method == "GET":
          print("get phase")
          return render_template("patientreg.html")

      else:
          print("post phase")
          name_surname=request.form['name_surname']
          emailadd=request.form['email']
          # weight=request.form['weight']
          # height=request.form['']
          ssn=request.form['ssn']
          age=request.form['age']
          # gender=request.form['gender']
          # symptoms=request.form['symptoms']

      cursor.execute('select * from Patients')
      patients = cursor.fetchall()
      print(patients)

      check = True

      for patient in patients:
          print(patient[0])

      if check == True:
          cursor.execute("insert into patients(name_surname,emailadd, ssn)"
                         "values(%s);",(name_surname,emailadd, ssn, age,))
          database.commit()
          print('done')
      else:
          print('failed')
          return redirect('/register/patient')

      return redirect('/login/')


  elif where == "doctor":
      pass
  return "Invalid Registration Attempt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"action"** and **"method"** are missing in the form.

```
<form id="regForm" action="/register/patient" method="POST">
```